# Is there a better way than using 2 SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that I have 2 tables, one with entries of films that an user likes and an other with events that an user has gone. Each table has a column for knowing the user. Something like:

Table Films:

```
id | iduser | film | number of watches | note ....
```

Table events:

```
id | iduser | event | date | ....
```

both iduser are connected with a relation to a table with other information of the user.

If I want to select some columns from table films and others from table events with the same iduser, is there a better way than 2 SELECT? I say this because each select has diferent number of rows so UNION gives me an error and join gives me like:

**EDIT**

```
FILM   | NOTE |     EVENT     | DATE
-----------------------------------------
tlor   |  9  | going to park  | 20/7/12
tlor   |  9  | eat a sandwich | 5/9/10
B film |  7  | going to park  | 20/7/12
B film |  7  | eat a sandwich | 5/9/10
```

**EDIT 2**

I say only a select because I think is the faster way but if there's a faster way, please let me know it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the output that you'd like, I don't understand why you wouldn't want to `JOIN` if pulling data from 2 related tables.

Comment: Use inner join to get all required fields for each user as one record and let the application handle the rest.

Comment: I think `SELECT *.Films, *.events FROM Films, events WHERE iduser=` will work too

Comment: `SELECT *.Films, *.events FROM Films, events WHERE iduser.Films=iduser.events`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for some reason need to fetch your data in using exactly one SELECT you can unify your resultsets  for `UNION ALL` like this

```
SELECT 'film' type, iduser, film name, watches, note, NULL date
  FROM films
 WHERE iduser = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'event' type, iduser, event name, NULL, NULL, date
  FROM events
 WHERE iduser = ?
```

Another approach to grab all data in one go is to pack column values specific to particular table with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) into a `details` column and then [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it in client code

```
SELECT 'film' type, iduser, film name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', watches, note)) details
  FROM films
 WHERE iduser = 1
 GROUP BY iduser, film
UNION ALL
SELECT 'event' type, iduser, event name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', date)) 
  FROM events
 WHERE iduser = 1
 GROUP BY iduser, event
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e69c1/5)** demo

Comment: What do you think is faster on a big database?

Comment: Ok the point is yours. 2 SELECT = 2.01 s. SELECT UNION = 1.03

Answer (score 2):

Doing two SELECTs is the correct solution here. You're loading two different sets of data.

**IF** the two tables had similar schemas (e.g, same column names and types), you could combine the two using:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid = ? UNION SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userid = ?
```

However, this **will not** work sensibly with two tables with different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to UNION as others have mentioned, you can do this with multiple LEFT JOINS.

Something like

```
SELECT U.UID, F.FIELD1, E.FIELD1
    FROM USERS U
    LEFT JOIN EVENTS E ON U.USERID=E.USERID
    LEFT JOIN FILMS F ON U.USERID=F.USERID
    WHERE F.USERID IS NOT NULL OR F.USERID IS NOT NULL
```

Something like that could work based on your requirement.  This way if the row was an EVENT row it would have fields for your event and if it was a film record the film fields would be populated.

Comment: Your solution gave me the same result as mine